# Parse Double quotes copy past issue with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am coping a string having quotes like this `" "` after pasting the string which having this double-quote it changing shape and becoming
 `“ ”`

Now I am parsing this string with javascript but getting this 
double-quote issue because it is not same as a copy it.

`" "` changing `“ ”`

I have tried replacing ASCII of double-quote  also but it is not detecting this `“ ”` double quote

```
'The mechanism of “x” is not the way I want'.replace('\"', '"');
```

What is needed is to change `“ ”` in this `" "` so I can parse it with regular `" "` double quote

Comment: You are replacing `"` and not `“`. And you are replacing it with `\s` instead of `"`

Comment: You mean manual copy&paste from an editor?

Comment: `replace` takes first parameter as what you are looking to replace, and second parameter as what to replace it by.

Comment: Yes i want to replace “x” with "x"

Answer (score 1):

From an engine perspective, `"` is not the same as `“`, or `”`. This `'The mechanism of “x” is not the way i want'.replace('\"', '\s');` will need to become `'The mechanism of “x” is not the way i want'.replace(/[“”]/g, '"');`.

As small example of the regex is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/lv0OsW/1).